# Luhn algorithm Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, luhn

I am new to robot framework and trying to implement Luhn Algorithm.
I found the code in python and want to change it to Robot framework.

```
def cardLuhnChecksumIsValid(card_number):
""" checks to make sure that the card passes a luhn mod-10 checksum """

sum = 0
num_digits = len(card_number)
oddeven = num_digits & 1

for count in range(0, num_digits):
    digit = int(card_number[count])

    if not (( count & 1 ) ^ oddeven ):
        digit = digit * 2
    if digit > 9:
        digit = digit - 9

    sum = sum + digit

return ( (sum % 10) == 0 )
```

I started with robotscript and was stuck at statement if not (( count & 1 ) ^ oddeven ) can someone please help me convert the above code to robot script
is there a automated to change python code to robot ?

```
cardLuhnChecksumIsValid
[Arguments]    ${ICCID1}
${num_digits}    Get length    ${ICCID1}
${odd_even}    ${num_digits}
...    AND    ${1}
FOR    ${Count}    IN RANGE    0    ${num_digits}
${digit}    Convert To Integer    ${ICCID[${Count}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    *** Test Cases ***
Check - ICCID


    [Setup]    setup
    ${ICCID}    Card.get ICCID #get ICCID
    ${Result_Chksum}    cardLuhnChecksumIsValid    ${ICCID}
 
    [Teardown]    tearDown

*** Keywords ***
setup
    No Operation

tearDown
    No Operation

cardLuhnChecksumIsValid
    [Arguments]    ${ICCID_val}
    ${num_digits}    Get length    ${ICCID_val}
    ${oddeven}=    Evaluate    ( ${1} & ${num_digits} )
    FOR    ${Count}    IN RANGE    0    ${num_digits}
        ${digit}    Convert To Integer    ${ICCID_val[${Count}]}
        ${condition}=    Evaluate    not (( ${Count} & 1 ) ^ ${oddeven} )
        ${digit}=    Run Keyword If    ${condition}    Evaluate    (${digit}*2)
        ...    ELSE    Set Variable    ${digit}
        ${digit}=    Run Keyword If    (${digit} > 9)    Evaluate    (${digit} - 9)
        ...    ELSE    Set Variable    ${digit}
        ${Sum}=    Evaluate    (${Sum}+${digit})
    END
    ${result}=    Evaluate    (${Sum}%10)
    [Return]    ${result}
```

Comment: if the return value is 0 then the ICCID is verified.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at on the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword in the BuiltIn library. You can use that to rewrite:

```python
if not (( count & 1 ) ^ oddeven ):
    digit = digit * 2
```

to:

```
${condition}=    Evaluate    not (( ${count} & 1 ) ^ ${oddeven} )
${digit}=    Run Keyword If    ${condition}    Evaluate    ${digit} * 2
```

You can rewrite the rest of the algorithm using the same approach. From Robot Framework 3.2 release you can also use [Inline Python evaluation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#inline-python-evaluation).